# Issue with OneHotEncoder for categorical features

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-extraction, categorical-data

I want to encode 3 categorical features out of 10 features in my datasets. I use `preprocessing` from [sklearn.preprocessing](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) to do so as the following:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
cat_features = ['color', 'director_name', 'actor_2_name']
enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=cat_features)
enc.fit(dataset.values)
```

However, I couldn't proceed as I am getting this error:

```
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: PG
```

I am surprised why it is complaining about the string as it is supposed to convert it!! Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you read the docs for `OneHotEncoder` you'll see the input for `fit` is "Input array of type int". So you need to do two steps for your one hot encoded data

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
cat_features = ['color', 'director_name', 'actor_2_name']
enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
enc.fit(cat_features)
new_cat_features = enc.transform(cat_features)
print new_cat_features # [1 2 0]
new_cat_features = new_cat_features.reshape(-1, 1) # Needs to be the correct shape
ohe = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(sparse=False) #Easier to read
print ohe.fit_transform(new_cat_features)
```

**Output**:

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]]
```

**EDIT**

As of `0.20` this became a bit easier, not only because `OneHotEncoder` now handles strings nicely, but also because we can transform multiple columns easily using `ColumnTransformer`, see below for an example

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np

X = np.array([['apple', 'red', 1, 'round', 0],
              ['orange', 'orange', 2, 'round', 0.1],
              ['bannana', 'yellow', 2, 'long', 0],
              ['apple', 'green', 1, 'round', 0.2]])
ct = ColumnTransformer(
    [('oh_enc', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False), [0, 1, 3]),],  # the column numbers I want to apply this to
    remainder='passthrough'  # This leaves the rest of my columns in place
)
print(ct2.fit_transform(X)) # Notice the output is a string
```

**Output:**

```
[['1.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '1.0' '0.0' '0.0' '1.0' '1' '0']
 ['0.0' '0.0' '1.0' '0.0' '1.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '1.0' '2' '0.1']
 ['0.0' '1.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '1.0' '1.0' '0.0' '2' '0']
 ['1.0' '0.0' '0.0' '1.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '0.0' '1.0' '1' '0.2']]
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer at all. Where do you fit your encoders with data from dataset ? Could you please provide more elaborate example with dataset from the question ?

Comment: How do you do this in a pipline?

Comment: Honestly, the naming of variables is confusing. cat_features is not the list of categorical features in a dataset but it is dataset itself with 1 column which is categorical. LabelEncoder encodes one categorical variable at a time

Comment: Regarding EDIT: Using a Pandas dataframe allows for mixed typed output. 
```X = pd.DataFrame([['apple', 'red', 1, 'round', 0], ...``` with ```ct = ColumnTransformer([('oh_enc', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False), [0, 1])], ...``` preoduces mixed output: ```[[1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1 'round' 0.0]...```

Answer (score 14):

You can apply both transformations (from text categories to integer categories, then from integer categories
to one-hot vectors) in one shot using the LabelBinarizer class:

```
cat_features = ['color', 'director_name', 'actor_2_name']
encoder = LabelBinarizer()
new_cat_features = encoder.fit_transform(cat_features)
new_cat_features
```

Note that this returns a dense NumPy array by default. You can get a sparse matrix instead by passing
sparse_output=True to the LabelBinarizer constructor.

Source [Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow](https://books.google.sn/books?id=khpYDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=labelbinarizer%20scikit%20learn&source=bl&ots=kLzsNPBnm3&sig=Ebo-s3CQgffwJvD9-A3r9zrRhJE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp96XnupvVAhUD0xoKHbtVDD8Q6AEITzAI#v=onepage&q=labelbinarizer%20scikit%20learn&f=false)

Answer (score 7):

If the dataset is in pandas data frame, using

> pandas.get_dummies

will be more straightforward.

*corrected from pandas.get_getdummies to pandas.get_dummies

Comment: Yeah this was so much easier!

Comment: with get_dummies, I am still struggling to get a consistent OHE between test and train dataset without merging them first

Answer (score 5):

from the documentation:

```
categorical_features : “all” or array of indices or mask
Specify what features are treated as categorical.
‘all’ (default): All features are treated as categorical.
array of indices: Array of categorical feature indices.
mask: Array of length n_features and with dtype=bool.
```

column names of pandas dataframe won't work. if you categorical features are column numbers 0, 2 and 6 use :

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
cat_features = [0, 2, 6]
enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=cat_features)
enc.fit(dataset.values)
```

It must also be noted that if these categorical features are not label encoded, you need to use `LabelEncoder` on these features before using `OneHotEncoder`

Answer (score 2):

A comment to @piman314's answer (not enough reputation to make a comment)

This problem only happens for sklearn version <= 0.19. [Documentation of 0.19](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) for fit method only allows integer input:

> fit(X, y = None)
>
> X: Input array of type int.

Later version ([documentation of 0.20](https://scikit-learn.org/0.20/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder)) automatically deal with the input datatype and allows string input

> fit(X, y = None)
>
> X: The data to determine the categories of each feature.

Answer (score 1):

@Medo,

I encountered the same behavior and found it frustrating. As others have pointed out, Scikit-Learn requires *all* data to be numerical before it even considers selecting the columns provided in the `categorical_features` parameter.

Specifically, the column selection is handled by the `_transform_selected()` method in /sklearn/preprocessing/data.py and the very first line of that method is

`X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csc', copy=copy, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)`.

This check fails if *any* of the data in the provided dataframe `X` cannot be successfully converted to a float.

I agree that the documentation of sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder is very misleading in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple fix if, like me, you get frustrated by this. Simply use [Category Encoders' OneHotEncoder](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/onehot.html). This is a Sklearn Contrib package, so plays super nicely with the scikit-learn API.

This works as a direct replacement and does the boring label encoding for you.

```
from category_encoders import OneHotEncoder
cat_features = ['color', 'director_name', 'actor_2_name']
enc = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=cat_features)
enc.fit(dataset.values)
```