# Scikit-Learn Numpy - Use One Hot Encoder on only string or categorical columns in dataset

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a simple linear regression model below that uses one hot encoding to transform every X value. My question is how can I modify the code below to use one hot encoding for every column except one (e.g. the integer one highlighted below)

[image]

```
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
# define the location of the dataset
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/breast-cancer.csv"
# load the dataset
dataset = read_csv(url, header=None)


# retrieve the array of data
data = dataset.values
# separate into input and output columns
X = data[:, :-1].astype(str)
y = data[:, -1].astype(str)


# split the dataset into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=1)

# one-hot encode input variables that are objects
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
onehot_encoder.fit(X_train)
X_train = onehot_encoder.transform(X_train)
X_test = onehot_encoder.transform(X_test)


# ordinal encode target variable
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.fit(y_train)
y_train = label_encoder.transform(y_train)
y_test = label_encoder.transform(y_test)

# define the model
model = LogisticRegression()
# fit on the training set
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
# predict on test set
yhat = model.predict(X_test)
# evaluate predictions
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, yhat)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
```

I tried only feeding in 8 columns instead of 9 to OHE but got the error:

```
ValueError: The number of features in X is different to the number of features of the fitted data. The fitted data had 9 features and the X has 8 features.
```

Comment: Cannot replicate the problem with this question, running your code I got an accuracy of around 70%. Could you be more specific in question.

Comment: See answer to similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68395936/7008257