# Using OneHotEncoder for categorical features in decision tree classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I am new to ML in Python and very confused by how to implement a decision tree with categorical variables as they get automatically encoded by `party` and `ctree` in `R`.

I want to make a decision tree with two categorical independent features and one dependent class.

The dataframe I am using looks like this:

```
data
      title_overlap_quartile sales_rank_quartile rank_grp
    0                     Q4                  Q2    GRP 1
    1                     Q4                  Q3    GRP 1
    2                     Q2                  Q1    GRP 1
    3                     Q4                  Q1    GRP 1
    5                     Q2                  Q1    GRP 2
```

I understood that categorical features need to be encoded in scikit learn using labelencoder and/or one hot encoder.

First I tried to just use label encoder but that does not solve the problem since `DecisionTreeClassifier` started treating the encoded variables as continuous. Then I read from this post: [Issue with OneHotEncoder for categorical features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588679/issue-with-onehotencoder-for-categorical-features) that the variable should first be encoded using label encoder and then encoded again using one hot encoder.

I tried to implement that on this dataset in the following way but am getting an error.

```
def encode_features(df, columns):
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    ohe = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
    for i in columns:
        le.fit(df[i].unique())
        df[i+'_le'] = le.transform(df[i])
        df[i+'_le'] = df[i+'_le'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
        df[i+'_le'+'_ohe'] = ohe.fit_transform(df[i+'_le'])
    return(df)

data = encode_features(data, ['title_overlap_quartile', 'sales_rank_quartile'])


  File "/Users/vaga/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2800, in _sanitize_index
    raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

When I remove the `ohe` part from the function and run it outside , it runs but the results look weird:

```
def encode_features(df, columns):
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    ohe = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
    for i in columns:
        le.fit(df[i].unique())
        df[i+'_le'] = le.transform(df[i])
        # df[i+'_le'] = df[i+'_le'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
        # df[i+'_le'+'_ohe'] = ohe.fit_transform(df[i+'_le'])
    return(df)

data = encode_features(data, ['title_overlap_quartile', 'sales_rank_quartile']) 

data['title_overlap_quartile_le'] = data['title_overlap_quartile_le'].values.reshape(-1, 1)

print(ohe.fit_transform(data['title_overlap_quartile_le']))

[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
   1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
   1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
   1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

I also tried using `pandas.get_dummies` which converts the variable into multiple columns with binary coding and used it, but that again gets treated as a continuous variable by the decision tree classifier.

Can someone please help me with how to fit a decision tree using the categorical variables as categorical and output the tree diagram?

The code for fitting and drawing the tree I am using is:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(data[['title_overlap_score', 'sales_rank_quartile']], data[['rank_grp']])

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None, feature_names=data[['title_overlap_score', 'sales_rank_quartile']].columns,  
                         filled=True, rounded=True,  
                         special_characters=True)  

graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)  
graph.render("new_tree")
```

Answer (score 2):

Although decision trees are supposed to handle categorical variables, sklearn's implementation cannot at the moment due to [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4899) unresolved bug. The current workaround, which is sort of convoluted, is to one-hot encode the categorical variables before passing them to the classifier.

Have you tried [category_encoders](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/categorical-encoding)? This is easier to handle, and can also be used within pipelines.

The [latest](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.CategoricalEncoder.html) yet to be released version of scikit-learn seems to allow string column types, without conversion to int.