# How can I encode a categorical column with the codes I want?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I've got a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'months': ['FEBRUARY', 'MARCH', 'MAY', 'DECEMBER', 'MAY']})
```

And I want to get:

```
[['JANUARY', 1], ['FEBRUARY', 2], ['MARCH', 3]]
```

I think it should be very easy but, when y try with this dummy example from sklearn:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
X = [[1,'Male'], [ 3,'Female']]
enc.fit(X)
```

I get the next error:

```
 ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Male'
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: You need to use a [`LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) before your can use the `OneHotEncoder`, but also it looks like `LabelEncoder` is what you actually want in this case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with OneHotEncoder for categorical features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588679/issue-with-onehotencoder-for-categorical-features)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `map`

```
gender = {'male':1,'female':3}
df.gender.map(gender)
```

Comment: is this task very expensive when working with a 3million rows df?